# How to remove/add quotes?

Tags: vim

I would like a command to remove/add quotes

```
"This is a text" ->  This is a text
 This is a text  -> "This is a text"
```

Is there some?

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simple_Macros_to_quote_and_unquote_a_word

Comment: +1, and no idea why someone downvoted. I think this is good question, direct way to get to know about mighty surround plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, go to *command mode*, then type :

```
:%s/\(^"\|"$\)//g
```

To quote lines :

```
:%s/\(^\|$\)/"/g
```

This performs substitution on all lines, adapt it to your needs if needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the popular [surround.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697):

- `yss"` surrounds a line with quotes.
- `ds"` deletes the closest surrounding quotes.

See also [this tutorial](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-surround-vim/) for more examples of what you can do with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting quotes you can simulate a new object `o"` meaning "outside quotes":

```
nnoremap do" di"viwp
```

Type `do"` in a quoted text and you'll get the text without quotes.

For adding quotes you could do (though this only works linewise):

```
nnoremap yo" I"<end>"<esc>
```

If you use surround.vim you can use yss" to quote an entire line without having to map a new command for it.